# Istio mesh breaks with "Duplicate entry" error

Tags: istio

The mysterious bug was causing two things to happen

1. None of my `VirtualServices` were working despite being correctly formatted and having checked the fields several times.
2. On `istioctl proxy-status` the entire `RDS` column was `STALE`.

Upon looking at the istio-proxy logs `-c discovery` (`grep`ing for `RDS`), I saw the following error.

```
2019-02-27T19:09:58.644652Z    warn    ads     ADS:RDS: ACK ERROR ... ... ... "Only unique values for domains are permitted. Duplicate entry of domain 172.16.x.y"
```

How do I fix this?

### Info

Istio version 1.0.6

Kubernetes version 1.10.x-gke

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this was that IP address in the log. After searching for where in my configuration I had that IP address, it turns out it was in my `ServiceEntries`.

One of my `ServiceEntries` looked like this:

```
spec:
  addresses:
  - 172.16.x.y
  hosts:
  - 172.16.x.y
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: http
    number: 80
    protocol: HTTP
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```

It turns out you cannot have multiple ports in there. I deleted the HTTPS block and, like magic, everything worked. The `istioctl proxy-status` command displayed everything in the `RDS` as `SYNCED` and all of my `VirtualServices` started working again.